# Array from split String problems

Tags: java, string, input, split, output

Hello I am using the following java code to split user input into individual words -

```
String command = scanner.next();
command = command.toLowerCase();
String[] words = command.split(" ");
```

- however when i try to print " words[1] " for an input with two or more words it throws a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. It would seem that words[1] would simply be the second word in the sentence but the array does not contain it.

Comment: its just because of may be it wont have that size. dont u think that? might be

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `scanner.next()`, try

```
String command = scanner.nextLine();
```

This will make sure you read all the words.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Scanner API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

While the javadoc for `Scanner#next()` states:

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern.

So in your case `scanner.next()` will return a word *with no whitespace*, as whitespace is how your scanner likely knows when to stop scanning.

You might want to use `Scanner#nextLine()` or something of the sort instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, and make sure you have read all input words

```
Scanner scanner = Scanner(System.in);
String command = scanner.nextLine();
command = command.toLowerCase();
String[] words = command.split(" ");
```

Now you can print

```
words[1]
```

if you have valid index value,